# Zip file is downloading with 20 bytes and when extracts the file it shows corrupted file and 'no archive found'

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

When i trying to download the zip file with the following code in my local system,the file is downloading with all the files but where as in server it is downloading with 20 bytes and when extracts file is corrupted and no archive found.So i added some checks for this code and run but this time File not found,going inside this check(if (!is_file($archive_file_name))).What might be the problem on server?

```
function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
        if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
            exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
        }

        //add each files of $file_name array to archive
        foreach($file_path as $file_path)
        {
            if(basename($file_path) =="documents")
            {

                foreach($file_names as $value=>$files)
                {
                    $customer_files = $this->fetchCustomFieldValuesAndFieldNamesByOrder($files['order_id']);
                    if($customer_files['field_value'] !="" && file_exists($file_path.$customer_files['field_value']))
                    {
                        $file_extension = pathinfo($customer_files['field_value'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        $zip_file_name = $files['customer_name']."_"."Files.".$file_extension;
                        $zip->addFile($file_path.$customer_files['field_value'],$zip_file_name);
                    }
                    //echo $customer_files['field_value']."<br>";
                }
            } else
            {
                foreach($file_names as $value=>$files)
                {

                    if($files['file_name'] !="" && file_exists($file_path.$files['file_name']))
                {
                    $file_extension = pathinfo($files['file_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $zip_file_name = $files['customer_name']."_"."Application".".$file_extension";
                    $zip->addFile($file_path.$files['file_name'],$zip_file_name);
                        //  echo $file_path.$files['file_name'],$zip_file_name."<br>";
                }

                }
        }
        }
        //  echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
        //  echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
        $zip->close();//exit;
     //then send the headers to foce download the zip file
        if (headers_sent()) {
            echo 'HTTP header already sent';
        } else {
            if (!is_file($archive_file_name)) {
                header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
                echo 'File not found';
            } else if (!is_readable($archive_file_name)) {
                header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
                echo 'File not readable';
            } else {
                header("Content-type: application/zip");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Expires: 0");
                readfile("$archive_file_name");
                exit;
            }
        }
            }
```

Comment: what does $zip->getStatusString() tell you? any errors?

Comment: When i do echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n"; this, it shows the status 11

Comment: Maybe a problem with the URL you're using or the rights to access it.
If you open your 20 bytes corrupted zip with notepad, you should see html code saying somthing went wrong ^^

Comment: The downloaded file is showing 0 bytes and when i open it with notepad it shows empty

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting status 11 from $zip->status, it means that the file you're trying to ZIP does not exist. Here are docs on error codes from the Zip / ZipArchive class: http://php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php

Verify that the path you're on is correct using [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) and that the file on this path really exists.

Comment: The file does not exist and it is permission problem,i resolved it

Comment: if this answer and others helped you in the past, please consider accepting them - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work